# opencv video reading slow framerate

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to read a video with OpenCV in C++, but when the video is displayed, the framerate is very slow, like 10% of the original framerate.

The whole code is here:

```
// g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` play-video.cpp -o play-video
// ./play-video [video filename]

#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // video filename should be given as an argument
    if (argc == 1) {
        cerr << "Please give the video filename as an argument" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    const string videofilename = argv[1];

    // we open the video file
    VideoCapture capture(videofilename);

    if (!capture.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "Error when reading video file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // we compute the frame duration
    int FPS = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    cout << "FPS: " << FPS << endl;

    int frameDuration = 1000 / FPS;  // frame duration in milliseconds
    cout << "frame duration: " << frameDuration << " ms" << endl;

    // we read and display the video file, image after image
    Mat frame;
    namedWindow(videofilename, 1);
    while(true)
    {
        // we grab a new image
        capture >> frame;
        if(frame.empty())
            break;

        // we display it
        imshow(videofilename, frame);

        // press 'q' to quit
        char key = waitKey(frameDuration); // waits to display frame
        if (key == 'q')
            break;
    }

    // releases and window destroy are automatic in C++ interface
}
```

I tried with a video from a GoPro Hero 3+, and with a video from my MacBook's webcam, same problem with both videos. Both videos are played without problem by VLC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does .get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) give you the correct fps? your waitKey is too big! imshow needs quite a lot of cimputation too (e.g. couldnt get 100 fps displayed with imshow). and keep in mind that waitKey is inaccurate especially if you choose small wait times. better switch to some "better" rendering like qt with openGL or directShow for example. openCV gui is more for testing than for enduser gui!

Comment: Yes, `.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)` gives me the correct FPS. My mistake is that I didn't thought that grabbing a frame and displaying it would would need that much computation. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I used below's answer to compute the time to grab the frame (not including the time to display it), it's about 20ms. To play the video at normal rate, it should be 8ms. Is there any solution to reduce that time?

Comment: dont use opencv for displaying but openGL. And/Or use a faster system.

Comment: yes, but even without the display part, it's still far too long to just get the new frame. I'm very surprised that with a MacBookPro with an i7 it's that slow.

Comment: ok sorry,... does your camera provide some SDK to capture frames directly? Do you use openCV release mode libraries? What's the resolution of your frames? Can you time-measure different operations? Some systems (e.g. windows OS) don't provide fine timing resolution, not sure about OS-X there (but should have fine-timing I guess). How are your cameras connected?

Comment: Or do you really use VIDEOS (video files)? Can you move the files to SSD or Ramdisk?

Comment: I use video files, they are already on a SSD. The GoPro Hero 3+ images are 720p. With OS X, the mean to grab a new frame is 24ms, the mean to show a picture with imshow is 4ms, so if I use the 120 FPS mode of the GoPro, I am 20ms behind schedule (should be 8ms between frames). I tried to measure time for the same program with the same video with a Linux running inside a VirtualBox on the same machine, and surprisingly it's faster despite the VM: mean grab time: 14ms, mean imshow time: 2ms, so I'm behind of schedule by 8ms only.

Comment: what codec is used? loading a single jpeg image might be much faster than cpu h.264 decoding... but probably should be fast enough on your machine... You could try to split the `capture >> frame;` into `capture.grab` (load from file) and `capture.retrieve` (decode frame) to find out which step is too slow.

Comment: The videos are encoded with mp4. I can't use jpeg because I want to make a program that will count points at table tennis, so I need to work on a video stream (or maybe several video streams, or in combination with a Kinect). On Max OS X, it's 7ms to grab the picture and 15ms to retrieve it. On Linux, it's 10ms to grab the picture, and 3ms to retrieve it.

Comment: so decoding the image is the slow(er) part (although grabbing seems to be too slow too). Can you try to find out whether openCV is compiled with an ffmpeg library version that supports hardware (maybe GPU) decoding for h.264 images?

Comment: performance difference between linux and os x might be because of different ffmpeg/opencv versions? http://answers.opencv.org/question/40899/ffmpeg-performance-decrease-after-opencv-246-to-249-upgrade-on-windows/

Comment: I didn't found if it supports GPU. I think I'm gonna try first to use smaller definition or smaller FPS settings for the GoPro. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try reducing the `waitKey` frame wait time. You are effectively waiting for the frame rate time (i.e. 33 ms), plus all the time it takes to grab the frame and display it. This means that if capturing the frame and displaying it takes over 0ms (which it does), you are guaranteed to be waiting for too long. Or if you really want to be accurate, you could time how long that part takes, and wait for the remainder, e.g. something along the lines of:

```
while(true)
{
    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    capture >> frame;
    if(frame.empty())
        break;
    imshow(videofilename, frame);

    auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();

    //make sure we call waitKey with some value > 0
    int wait_time = std::max(1, elapsed_time);

    char key = waitKey(wait_time); // waits to display frame
    if (key == 'q')
        break;
}
```

The whole `int wait_time = std::max(1, elapsed_time);` line is just to ensure that we wait for at least 1 ms, as OpenCV needs to have a call to `waitKey` in there to fetch and handle events, and calling `waitKey` with a value <= 0 tells it to wait infinity for a user input, which we don't want either (in this case)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed as said in comments above, I didn't expected the time to grab a frame to be that big, because the video plays smoothly with players such as VLC. Is there a solution to reduce the time to grab a frame?

Comment: there are many reasons that a piece of software can run slower than expected. Perhaps try using ffmpeg directly and/or use some hardware accelerated decoding? Reading 720p video should be much faster than what you are seeing